# iPhone - Using '*' as Badge

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, badge

I need a simple clarification in using badges for iPhone applications. Can I use '*' instead of numbers to display in badge? If so, will Apple accept such application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can not use `*` as a badge since the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` property will only take a `NSInteger`.

See the [`UIApplication` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)